# Magento 2 Purchase Order per Customer Group not Available Anymore?

Tags: magento2, customer-group, purchase-order

I believe limit PO to customer group such as wholesale was a standard `Magento 1` feature, whereas in `Magento 2` it seems not available?

Can someone confirm this, please?

Answer (score 2):

It's still there. I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2

Go to **Admin -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration**

`Sales -> Payment Methods` Tab

`Expand Purchase Order` Tab

[image]

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/Resources/pdf/Magento_Community_Edition_2.0_User_Guide.pdf Page 670

Comment: Yes I understand PO is still available as a payment method in `Magento 2`, but can you assign PO to specific customer group at all?

Comment: How u r doing in Magento 1 can provide link?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, both Magento 1 and Magento 2 do not support this function

Therefore, if you want to set up PO for customer group, you can do it manually with codes or install an extension

You can search in Magento marketplace by some key words such as payment for customer group 
There are some related extension shown. I can take an example for you:

https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-paymentshipping.html

This module can allow you to set up each payment method for customer group easily without codes